# Prove that for $a > 0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a^n}{n!}=0}$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{k^n}{n!} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80453/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracknn-0)

Prove that for $a > 0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a^n}{n!}=0}$. My attempt is since $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$ and the series converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, by the test of divergence, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a^n}{n!}=0}.$$ Is my proof correct ? or are there any alternative ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It's correct, but uses a "sledgehammer" in my opinion. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121386/how-to-prove-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-an-over-n-0?rq=1) and its links for more elementary methods.

Comment: This is also true for $a\leq 0$.

Comment: The proof is correct but, as @DavidMitra says, you're using a sledgehammer :) So I don't find it very clean, you should be able to prove then that those series are equal to $e^x$ and that they converge, using taylor's theorem also does the trick but it's more advanced that the analysis corresponding to this. Final message: I would look for another proof, but if I saw this in an exam and nothing came to my mind, I would undoubtedly use yours and it would be correct.

Comment: @DavidMitra : What do you mean ' sledgehammer' in this case ?

Comment: By "sledgehammer', I mean that you're using  a comparatively sophisticated result (the infinite series converges) to prove a result which can otherwise be proven using more elementary methods.  This is fine; but a proof that uses only as much machinery as needed (in this case, all you need is that $a/n<1/2$ for $n$ sufficiently large and the comparision test for limits) would be preferable to some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of providing a (hopefully intuitive) alternative, since you asked for it:

By expanding the factorial (and thereby hopefully making it more tangible) it is fairly easy to see that it grows quicker than the exponential.

$$\frac{a^n}{n!} = \frac{a}{1}\frac{a}{2}\frac{a}{3}\ldots\frac{a}{n}$$

The exponential is simply the repeated product of $n$ number of $a$'s, whereas the factorial is the repeated product of $n$ *ever-growing* integers.

Therefore there must come a point, some $n \ge a$, after which all new factors of the denominator must be larger than the new factors of the numerator. This gap in the size of $a$ and $n$ will only continue to grow; the final factor itself, $\frac{a}{n}$, goes to $0$ as $n$ does, and so the product of an infinite amount of such small fractions has little choice but to follow suit and approach $0$.