# A limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove the following limit

$$(\frac{2^n}{n!}) \to 0$$

But it seems difficault to me. How can I prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Likely to be a duplicated. Notice that $2^n/n! = 2/1\cdot 2/2 \cdot 2/3 \cdot 2/4 \dots \leq 2\cdot (2/3)^{n-2}$

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80453/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracknn-0) one duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
a_n =\frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac{2\cdot \ldots \cdot 2}{1\cdot 2\cdot \ldots \cdot n}
\end{align}
Assume, that $n\geq 4$, then 
\begin{align}
a_n =\frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac21\frac22\frac23\frac24 \cdot\ldots \cdot \frac2n
\end{align}
Now, all fractions between $\frac24$ and $\frac2n$ are smaller or equal $\frac24$, so you can bound your sequence
\begin{align}
a_n &=\frac{2^n}{n!} \leq \frac21\frac22\frac23\frac24 \frac24 \cdot\ldots \cdot \frac24\\
&= \frac21\frac22\frac23 \Bigl(\frac24\Bigr)^{n-3} =\frac86\Bigl(\frac24\Bigr)^{n-3} 
\end{align}
Do you know, what happens to $\Bigl(\frac24\Bigr)^{n-3} $ for $n\rightarrow \infty$?