# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a^n}{n!} = 0$

Tags: analysis

Show that for any a in $\mathbb{R}$

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}    \frac{a^n}{n!} = 0. $$ Hint: There exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n > |a|.$

I really do not know how to begin here with the proof and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042129/a-limit-of-a-sequence).

Comment: @DavidMitra: second question on this topic in last hour, and second answer using the series test to prove elementary convergence of a sequence in two days.

Comment: sry i dont have checked previously asked question but i thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Ilya At least, no one's suggested to use Stirling :)

Comment: @DavidMitra: I'm pretty sure the only reason for that is that we just haven't waited enough yet :)

Comment: @Ilya: I should read the comments before I answer. My answer was too close to some of the others, but seeing as this is a duplicate to several questions, I should not have answered in the first place.

Comment: @robjohn: by no means I was blaming you

Comment: @Ilya: I know... I was just noting that there were a lot of answers to a question which has been asked several times and I was one of them

Answer (score 1):

Pick any such $N$ and pick $r$ such that $\dfrac{|a|}{N}<r<1$. For all $n>N$

$$\dfrac{|a|^n}{n!} = \underbrace{\left|\dfrac{a}{1}\dfrac{a}{2}\dfrac{a}{3}\cdots \dfrac{a}{N}\right|}_{:= \ C}\left(\dfrac{|a|}{N+1}\dfrac{|a|}{N+2}\dfrac{|a|}{N+3}\cdots \dfrac{|a|}{n}\right)< Cr^{n-N}$$

Now $r<1$. So?

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=N+1$$
we have:
$$ n! = \frac{n^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}>e\cdot\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \tag{1}$$
because for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$ we have $\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k<e$. A straightforward consequence of $(1)$ is that:
$$\left|\frac{a^n}{n!}\right|<\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{|a|e}{n}\right)^n,$$
hence, assuming $n\geq 2e|a|$,
$$\left|\frac{a^n}{n!}\right| < \frac{1}{2^n}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $T_m=\dfrac{a^m}{m!},$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac a{n+1}=0$$ for finite $a$

So, $\sum T_r$ must converge  $\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n=0$

---

Alternatively for $N>|a|,$  $$\dfrac{a^m}{N!}<\frac aN$$