# Does the sequence $\frac{n!}{2^n}$ converge or diverge? 

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponentiation, factorial

Does the following sequence $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge?

> $$a_n=\dfrac{n!}{2^n}$$

Comment: Hint: try working out the values of the terms for values of $n$ like 10, 20, 30, ... then make a guess at the probable limit, and try to find a mathematical reason why it might be true? Ask us when/if you get stuck.

Comment: @OldJohn: I am a lecturer at a collage and suggest the same way to my students who don't know what to do at first. :)

Comment: Consider using Sterling formula to give you an approximation of n!.

Comment: See also [Show that the sequence $\left(\frac{2^n}{n!}\right)$ has a limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/251441) and [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider writing "out" the sequence:

$$\tag 1\frac{{n!}}{{{2^n}}} = \frac{n}{2}\frac{{n - 1}}{2}\frac{{n - 2}}{2} \cdots \frac{4}{2}\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{2}\frac{1}{2}$$

Note that every time we take another step in the sequence, we multiply by $\dfrac{n}{2}$ so we're making the sequence larger and larger each time. In particular, we can see that every term in the factorization in $(1)$ is larger or equal than $1$, except $1/2$, so that

$$\frac{{n!}}{{{2^n}}} = \frac{n}{2}\frac{{n - 1}}{2}\frac{{n - 2}}{2} \cdots \frac{4}{2}\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{2}\frac{1}{2} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n}{4}$$

What does this tell you about the limit of the sequence?

Another approach would be D'Alambert's criterion (ratio test), which gives:

$${a_n} = \frac{{n!}}{{{2^n}}}$$

So

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a_{n + 1}}}}{{{a_n}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}{{{2^{n + 1}}}}\frac{{{2^n}}}{{n!}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{a_{n + 1}}}}{{{a_n}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n + 1}}{2}\frac{{n!}}{{n!}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n + 1}}{2}  $$

What can you say about that limit? Then, what does this tell you about

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} \; \;?$$

Answer (score 6):

...and a very fancy proof:
$$\,a_n:=\frac{2^n}{n!}\Longrightarrow \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{2^n}=\frac{2}{n+1}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{} 0$$

so by d'Alembert's Test, the positive series $\,\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n!}}\,$ converges, and thus 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}=0\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{2^n}=\infty$$

Answer (score 5):

**HINT** $$\dfrac{n!}{2^n} \geq \dfrac{n}4 \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Part of Peter's subsequent [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/163894) expands on this hint.  Perhaps user1405177 could get good practice by proving this by induction.

Comment: I think sometimes it is better to explain where that comes from. It is of no use if the OP has no clue on how to deduce such inequality.

Comment: @Peter: How do we know whether or not the OP has a clue?  No such information was given.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That is true. My point is that it is better either hint or explain (depending on your stance on HW questions) how to **deduce** an useful inequality, rather than just to give it out plainly. This will help him in this case only, but nourishing the deductive abilities will help in broader cases. You know: "Teach a man to fish".

Comment: Can we use direct comparison test here?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another (somewhat roundabout) way to approach this. Noting that we've got $n!$ terms showing up, it suggests that the sequence is related to a Taylor series for some function.

Put $b_n=1/a_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and consider the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n.$$ Rewriting this as $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^n}{n!},$$ we see that $f(x)$ is simply the Taylor series of $e^{2x}$ about $x=0$, which converges for all $x$. In particular, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n=f(1)=e^2,$$ so the **series** with non-negative terms $b_n$ converges. What can we then conclude about the **sequence** of terms $b_n$? What does that tell us about the sequence of terms $a_n=1/b_n$?