# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What I have got:

For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we can find an $N$, $N\gt a$, such that, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=\frac{a}{1}\cdot\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{3}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{a}{N-1}\cdot\frac{a}{N}\cdot\frac{a}{N+1}\cdot\ldots,$ and the later part
$\frac{a}{N}\cdot\frac{a}{N+1}\cdot\ldots\lt\frac{a^m}{n^m}\to 0$ when $m\to\infty$, because $\frac{a}{n}\lt1$.

Then use the definition of convergence, with letting $M=\frac{a}{1}\cdot\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{3}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{a}{N-1}$, and $\frac{a^m}{n^m}\lt\delta$ for $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$.

For an n that is large enough, we have $\frac{a^n}{n!}\lt\epsilon$, $\forall\epsilon\gt 0$.

What I want to ask is:

Are there any other ways to prove that this limit tends to $0$?

Thanks!

Comment: i guess you totally aren't allowed to use stirlings approximation or ?

Comment: This has been asked over 9000 times here. Let me search.

Comment: See this [meta thread for FAQs on main](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r) for you question.

Comment: i think i did not learn stirlings approximation... thank you i will see that thread. :)

Answer (score 2):

We have for $a\neq 0$:
$$\log\frac{|a|^n}{n!}=n\log| a|-\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\sim_\infty n\log|a|-\int_1^n\log x dx=n\log|a|-n\log n\to-\infty$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the result, if $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=b $ and $|b|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = 0$. Applying this to your problem, we have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{a^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a}{n+1}=0 <1 $$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}=0. $$

Comment: @user66607: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If some asks a reasonable question is better to answer it straightforward than to elaborate into unnecessary details.
Use ratio test because it is more easier:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}}{{(n+1)}!}/\frac{a^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n+1}=0<1$.
Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$.
user66607 I hope you get it now.

Comment: ah thanks i get this one :)