# What is the result of $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ 2^n }{ n! } $ and why?

Tags: limits

What is the result of the next limit: $ \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ 2^n }{ n! } $

**Why (theorem)?**

Comment: You could of course use stirling, but its not really necessary.

Comment: @Prism Looked into it. It's definately a duplicate; flagged as such.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/77561/8581, I think, could be the best.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{2}{n - 1}\cdot  \frac{2}{n - 2}\cdot  \dots \cdot \frac{2}{2}\cdot  \frac{2}{1} \leq \frac{2}{n} \frac{2}{2} \frac{2}{2} ... \frac{2}{2} \frac{2}{1} = \frac{4}{n} \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$.