# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{n}}{n!} = 0$

Tags: analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{n}}{n!} = 0$ using the hint that $0 < \frac{2^{n}}{n!} \leq 2 \, \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-2}$ for all $n \geq 3$?
I know there is a thread already about this question but there is none that use this hint to solve this question. How can you use this hint to prove it?

Comment: Have you heard of the squeeze theorem?

Comment: yes but how do I get to 2(2/3)^(n-2)>=2^n/n!?

Comment: Like how would I get to the step of 2(2/3)^(n-2)?

Comment: Induction would work.

Comment: Could you explain more? I've tried induction but can't reach the conclusion.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r/77561#77561) uses exactly the approach from your hint.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is trivial for $n=3$. For the inductive step:

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac2{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n!}\le  \frac2{n+1}\times 2\left(\frac23\right)^{n-2}\le2 \left(\frac23\right)^{n-1}$$
since $n+1\ge3$.

Now to use the hint notice that the geometric sequence $\left(\frac23\right)^{n-2}$ is convergent to $0$ so we conclude the desired result using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: how do you get the inequality 2^n/n!<=2(2/3)^(n-2)?

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac1{3\times \cdots\times n}\le\frac1{3^{n-2}}$$
which is true since $$3\le k,\quad \forall 3\le k\le n$$

Comment: how can you prove that lim(2/3)^(n-2)=0? Using epsilon

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\rho<1,$$ by d'Alembert rule, $$\lim_{n\to\infty }a_n=0.$$

I let you try for $a_n=\frac{2^n}{n!}$ ;-)