# Is sequence limited and what is limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, factorial

I am stuck at one problem. So I have to check if sequence is convergent.

$$\frac{2^x}{x!}$$

My thinking was to calculate limit and if limit exists it's convergent, but I am struggling with this:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x}{x!} = ?$$

I can't do it with L'Hopital's rule or with logarithm. Does that mean that this sequence is divergent?

Comment: See also [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could note that for $n\ge 4$ you have 
$$\frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac2n \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \le \frac12 \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$ Thus by induction you get that for the $n$-th term 
$$\frac{2^n}{n!}\le \frac{1}{2^{n-3}} \frac{2^3}{3!}=2^{-n}  \ 64/6.$$ And, I assume you can finish this.

Comment: I will try that way. Will get back here soon.

Comment: I am still struggling with this :). So I have one more question. Can I take any $$k$$ and prove that for this $$n>k$$ sequence converges and that means that whole sequence converges?

Comment: This is not what I meant. Let us set $a_n = 2^n/n!$. The above shows $a_n \le 2^{-n} (64/6)$. Also $0 \le a_n$. If you can show that $2^{-n} (64/6)$ tends to $0$ as $n$ to $\infty$ you have showed that the original sequence converges to $0$. And showing $2^{-n}$ goes to $0$ is likely somenting you saw already.

Answer (score 1):

We know that$$e^x=\sum\dfrac{x^n}{n!}.$$ So we have $$e^2=\sum\frac{2^n}{n!}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n!}=0$$

Comment: I'm not sure he can use this, or else he wouldn't be asking this question

Comment: I didn't now for first expression. I will have to check it I guess! But this looks really nice!

Answer (score 0):

I take it from your notation that x is a positive integer. let $U_x$ be your sequence.

Then suppose x>3 :

x!=1*2*3*..*x > $2*3^{x-2}$

->  0 < $U_x < \frac{2^x}{2*3^{x-2}} = 3*(\frac{2}{3})^{x-1}$

=> ($U_x$) ->0 , when x->∞

Comment: But what if x is number in R? Because x can be negative too.

Comment: No it cannot be because x! doesn't exist for a negative integer, or at least should you prove very carefully what you mean by x!
 Which brings me to the next point: x! only exists for positive integers, when x is just a real number you want to study the gamma function evaluated in x+1. Doing so you can frame it with factorials of floor(x) and floor(x+1).
Here is the wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function