# Calculus - Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}=0$$

I tried to prove it using epsilon-delta, but I still haven't managed to prove it.

I think that maybe with sandwich theorem it possible to prove it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have that $x>0$?

Comment: $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{x^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{n+1} = 0 <1 $$

Comment: I don't understand, Could you please add a few more steps?

Comment: If $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = c < 1$ then $\lim a_n = 0$, with $a_n > 0$. It's a result. In this case we have $a_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_0$ be such that $|x|<n_0$. Then
$|\lim_{n\geq 1}\frac {x^n}{n!}|=|\frac{x^{n_0-1}}{(n_0-1)!} \lim_{n\geq n_0}\frac {x^{n-n_0+1}}{n_0\cdots n}|\leq |\frac{x^{n_0-1}}{(n_0-1)!} \lim_{n\geq n_0}\left(\frac {x}{n_0}\right)^{n-n_0+1}| =0$