# prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3e^n}{n!}=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3e^n}{n!}=0$?

$e^n=e\cdot e\cdots e$, $n$-times. I tried to find  a constant $C>0$ and a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{3e^n}{n!}\le C\frac{e}{n}$ for $n\ge N$, to apply the squeezing lemma afterwards. But I don't know how to estimate the fraction $\frac{3e^n}{n!}$, how can I estimate $\frac{3e^n}{n!}$ from above? Thank you.

Comment: Show that $a_{n+1}/a_n\to0$ where $a_n=3e^n/n!$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992029/calculus-prove-lim-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0?rq=1

Comment: sorry, I have overseen the already existing questions despite googling first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{e^{n}}{n!}&\leq\dfrac{e}{1}\cdot\dfrac{e}{2}\cdot\dfrac{e}{3}\cdots\dfrac{e}{3},~~~~n\geq 3\\
&=\dfrac{e^{2}}{2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{e}{3}\right)^{n-2}\\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}

Comment: And there is nothing special about $e$.

Comment: Yes, then choose large $n\geq a$ for any $a>1$ and do it in this fashion.

Comment: thank you very much, it answeres my question

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative solution: the series $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$converges absolutely for any $x\in\Bbb R$ (as easily seen by the ratio test). In particular, it converges when $x=e$. A necessary condition for series convergence is that the sequence being summed tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: this is an awesome solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint1 the series $$\sum\frac{e^n}{n!}=e^e$$ converges

Hint2 Use Stirling formula
[Stirling's formula: proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/stirlings-formula-proof)

$$ n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Comment: thank you. Nice to see this alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's obvious that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_n = \frac{3e^n}{n!}\geq 0$.

Now let's study its behaviour: $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{e^n}=\frac{e^1}{n+1}$$, thus the sequence is decreasing, minored by $0$, thus its limit is $0$.

Comment: thank you. Nice to see this alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Every time you increase $n$, you multiply the previous term by $e$ and divide it by the new $n$. Obviously the factors are very soon smaller than $1$.