# Convergence, finding limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

I just came across an exercise, however I don't know how to find the limit of $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}$$ can any body help? 
Of course this is not homework, I'm only trying out example myself, from https://people.math.osu.edu/fowler.291/sequences-and-series.pdf page 38.

I know that the limit exists, and it is $0$, checked it in on the wolfram, but I don't know how to solve it.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $n!>3^{n-2}$ as you multiply $n-2$ factors $3$ or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a_n:=\frac{2^n}{n!}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{2^n}=\frac2{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies$$

the infinite series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;\;\;\text{converges}\;\;\implies\;\;a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Notice that

$$\frac{2^n}{n!} = {{2 *2*2*2*...*2} \over {1*2*3*4*...*n}}=2*{{2*2*...*2} \over {3*4*...*n}} \leq 2*1*1*...*{{2} \over {n}}={4 \over n}$$

So

$$0 \leq \frac{2^n}{n!} \leq {4 \over n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

And hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}=0$

Comment: interesting, however I find it more intuitive, to simply show that $a_{n+1}/a_n < 1$, as in the answer given by Timbuc.

Comment: @Chris Your second inequality is false for $\;n=2,3,4\;$ at least...;)

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: A rather similar approach together with a generalization is explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r/134181#134181).

Answer (score 0):

Generalization for $1<a<k<n$: 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} < a^{k-1} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^{n-k}}{k(k+1) \ldots n} = k^k \lim_{n \to \infty} \big(\frac{a}{k})^n =0
$$
The last step is since $k(k+1) \ldots n >k^{n-k}$

Comment: That inequality looks pretty suspicious: you cancel one $\;2\;$ both in numerator and denominator...and then you keep all the rest of factors  of the denominator yet **all** the other twos in the numerator disappear?

Comment: If $n>1$ then : $\frac{2...2}{1.2.3...n}\leq \frac{4}{n}$ is easier to show and does the job.

Comment: But for example for $\;n=3\;$ , the inequality says that $$\frac43=\frac{2^3}{3!}<\frac1{3} ....\text{I doubt it. Am I missing something?}$$

Comment: Apologies, solution fixed.