# Limiting value of $\frac{x^n e^x}{n!}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

For the Taylor Series the remainder is of the form $$R_n = \frac{(x-a)^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(\xi) $$ with $a \leq \xi \leq x$

For the series of $e^x$ about $0$ (that is, the Maclaurin series) the remainder is 
$R_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}e^{\xi}$ with $0 \leq \xi \leq x$. Now, I have to prove that as $n \to \infty$ this $R_n \to 0$. How do I go about it? My problem is that I know nothing about $x$ and whether it is bigger or smaller than $n$.

In short, how do I prove  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{\xi}=0$$

Comment: Fix $x$ and then take the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x$ in some interval $[a,b]$, $x^n e^\zeta \leq b^n e^b$. Now $e^b$ is just some constant, and can be ignored. You are now looking at
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b^n}{n!},$$
which can be handled in very many ways. For a reference on these, see the answers to the question [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550/9754)

Answer (score 1):

$e^\xi$ is just a constant. Use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to write

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}=
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{ex}{n}\right)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
For $n>ex$ the term in the brackets is $<1$ and then its clear that the limit is 0.