# What is the limit when n goes to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to find the limit of $\frac{(-3)^n}{n!}$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$ by the squeeze theorem or any other method?

Comment: Hint: when you increase $n$ by $1$, you multiply the term by $-3/n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r)

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n}{n!}$ converges because of the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test): $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{(-3)^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{(-3)^n/n!} \right\rvert = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{-3}{n+1}\right\rvert = 0 <1$. But this means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-3)^n}{n!} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$3^n\lt n!$ for sufficiently large $n$ and $\lim (-1)^n$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $n > 6$ we have that $\left|\frac{(-3)^n}{n!}\right| < \left|\frac{(-3)^6}{6!}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{n-6}\right|$. Now it's bounded by a sequence that you can show converges to $0$.