# Find $\ \limsup_{n\to \infty}(\frac{2^n}{n!}) $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial, limsup-and-liminf

Find$\ \limsup_{n\to \infty}(\frac{2^n}{n!}) $

The following 2 facts have already been proven.

1. $\ 2^n < n! $ for $n \ge 4$ (Proof by induction)
2. $\ \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} < \frac{2^n}{n!} $ for $\ n\ge 4 $

It would be sufficient to show that $\ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!} = 0 $

However, what are some ways to show this?

I have found a proof using the definition of convergence.

(For all $\ \epsilon > 0 $, Find N such that if n >= N, $\ |\frac{2^n}{n!} - 0| < \epsilon $)

However, I was wondering if there was a simpler proof.

Thanks!

Comment: Just strengthen the second fact a little, e.g. $LHS < r RHS$, for some $r<1$.  Then you can bound the sequence by a geometric one.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a little simpler: For large $n,$
$$\frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac{2}{n}\frac{2}{n-1}\cdots \frac{2}{3}\frac{2}{2}\frac{2}{1}\le \frac{4}{n(n-1)}\cdot 2 = \frac{8}{n(n-1)}\to 0.$$

Comment: Well done!  Concise and simple. +1

Comment: Out of curiosity, why stop at $\frac{\cdots}{n(n-1)}$? Couldn't you also ignore the $n-1$ factor?

Comment: Yes, I could have, good point. I think I thought "series" for a moment and just wrote it down. So in fact the above shows $\sum 2^n/n!$ converges, which is stronger.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative idea:

$e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges for all $x$ by the ratio test so, in particular, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!} = 0$.