# Show that the sequence $\left(\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)$ where $x\in(0,1)$ decreases monotonically and converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometric-series

I have to show that sequences $\left(\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)$ where $x\in(0,1)$ and $\left(-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)$ where $x\in(-1,0)$ decrease monotonically and converge to $0$.

I know that if $x\in(0,1)$ then the sequnce $(x^n)$ converges to $0$ but in this case I have the $(2k+1)!$

Comment: Your sequence is a subsequence of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Thus, [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r) can be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

It will enough to show that $$\frac{x^2}{(2k+2)(2k+3)}<1\qquad\text{for }0<x<1$$
Which is clear. So 
$$\frac{x^{2(k+1)+1}}{(2(k+1)+1)!}=\frac{x^2}{(2k+2)(2k+3)}\cdot\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}<\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
Then, the sequence is convergent.

On the other hand, the following argument shows that the sequence converges to zero:

Let $k\ge 1$ an integer, then for $-1<x<1$ we have
$$0\leq\left|\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right|\leq|x^{2k+1}|$$
And $|x^{2k+1}|_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, woul this be enough to show that the sequences decreases as well?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0 \leq \frac{x^2}{(2k+2)(2k+3)}<1\qquad\text{for }0<x<1$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\frac{|x|^{2k+1}/(2k+1)!}{|x|^{2k}/(2k)!}=\frac{|x|}{2k+1}<1\ \forall k\ge 0, \mathrm{if}\ x\in (-1,1)$$