# Prove convergence of alternating sequence with factorial in denominator $\frac{\left(-5\right)^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

How do I prove convergence of below alternating sequence with a factorial in the denominator?

$\{\frac{\left(-5\right)^n}{n!}\}$

How can I apply the principles described in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r) post to this question? What sequences can I use to apply Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: By using that post you can show separately that $-5^n/n! \to 0$ and $5^n/n! \to 0$; the result follows by the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Once you have $5^n/n! \to 0$, $(-5)^n/n! = (-1)^n5^n/n!$ also $\to 0$.

Comment: I don't agree that the given is  a duplicate of the linked OP since here the key point asked is how to apply the squeeze theorem. I'm asking an advice by moderators about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\left(-5\right)^n}{n!}=(-1)^n\frac{5^n}{n!}\to0$$

indeed

$$-\frac{5^n}{n!}\le (-1)^n\frac{5^n}{n!}\le \frac{5^n}{n!}$$

and by ratio test

$$\frac{5^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{5^n}=\frac{5}{n+1}\to 0$$