# How to find this limit: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{3^x}{x!}+1)}$

Tags: limits

Can you help me please how to find this limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{3^x}{x!}+1)}$$

Comment: Do you know the (asymptotic) behaviour of $\tfrac{a^x}{x!}$?

Comment: No, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r) that (for any constant $c$), we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{c^n}{n!}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $3^n<(n-1)!$ for $n\ge9$