# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10^n}{\sqrt{(n+1)!} + \sqrt{n!}}\,.$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10^n}{\sqrt{(n+1)!} + \sqrt{n!}}\,.$

I used the ratio criterion for the calculation and I got to this, can I say now that it is zero or is it still an undefined expression?

## $\frac{10+(10/\sqrt{(n+1)})}{\sqrt{(n+2)}+1}$

10/inf < 1 ----> lim an=0

Comment: $n!$ is "stronger", then any $n$s power.

Comment: I know, but it has to be proven somehow

Comment: Since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ approaches $0<1$, yes you can say that the original sequence approaches $0$.

Comment: yes, i just didn't know if the fraction I came across is a defined expression

Comment: @martin19875 you can easily see that it is $0$ just by separating the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10+\frac{10}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+2}+1}$$ So,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{10}{\sqrt{n+2}+1} + \frac{\frac{10}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+2}+1}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10}{\sqrt{n+2}+1} + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10}{(\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n+2}+1)} = 0$$ since both limits exist. So, since $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 0 < 1$$ you can say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using sandwich theorem is enough for this problem:
\begin{align}
0\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10^n}{\sqrt{(n+1)!} + \sqrt{n!}}&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{10^n}{\sqrt{n!}+\sqrt{n!}}\\
&=\dfrac12\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{100^n}{n!}}\\
&=\dfrac12\times\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{100^n}{n!}\right)}\\
&=0
\end{align}

Comment: it does not seem appropriate to set it hard to 0

Comment: @martin19875, what do you mean? I am assuming you know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}=0$ for any real $x$.

Comment: Otherwise use any proof from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r).

Comment: Yes, but it must be proved in the example. It is generally not appropriate for me to put 0 directly into the inequality

Comment: @martin19875, that is very standard limit. Most people (including me) use it directly in university exams.

Comment: You simplified well for the comments to be made, so it's we should vote for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$\frac{10^n}{\sqrt{(n+1)!} + \sqrt{n!}} \lt \frac{10^n}{2\sqrt{n!}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{100^n}{n!}}$$
we come to limit $\frac{a^n}{n!}$ for $a \gt 1$. Of course exists natural $k=\lfloor a\rfloor \leqslant a \leqslant \lfloor a\rfloor +1$. So we have
$$0 \lt \frac{a^n}{n!} = \frac{a}{1}\frac{a}{2} \cdots \frac{a}{k} \frac{a}{k+1}\cdots \frac{a}{n} \leqslant \frac{a}{1}\frac{a}{2} \cdots \frac{a}{k} \left(\frac{a}{k+1}\right)^{n-k} \to 0$$

Comment: Good answer, I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** No, it's not undefined, since the numerator goes to 11.

Just explaining a bit about the above answer:

$$100^n \leq  n!$$

and because we can see that:

$$n \cdot log(100) < log(n!) = \sum_{j = 0 }^{n} log(j)$$

for some $j = 100$, from this point the sums on the right will be bigger and overcome the difference, this is, on the left you are summing each time $log(100)$, but at some moment a gap will appear as we said, and this can be proved formally.

Comment: Don't you think that according to your reasoning, $numerator\to\ 11$ and $denominator\to\ \infty$ then the limit does not exist. Right?

Comment: Actually don't you think it's useful this answer? The function would be undefined at 0.

Comment: Oh ya.... I completely forgot about that... The denominator at $\infty$ is indeed defined....thanks @João Victor Melo

Answer (score 1):

I would like to completely eliminate the doubt regarding why " n! is 'stronger', then any ns power", with the aid of [Sterling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), and solve the question even without using the ratio test.....

$\frac{10^n}{\sqrt{(n+1)!} + \sqrt{n!}} \lt \frac{10^n}{2\sqrt{n!}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{100^n}{n!}}$

This inequality true because the denominator of right term is smaller than left term...

By the [Sterling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we have

$n!\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n}{e^n}$

Hence, at the limit to infinity, we can write
$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{100^n}{n!}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{100^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}~.({\frac{100}{n})}^n}=0$,  as the limit$\frac{100}{n}$ goes to 0..

Here the important fact is then 100, can be replaced by any real finite number..., hence proving why n! is stronger

Comment: This is like using cannon to kill a fly. The ratio test is much simpler way to handle it.

Comment: sure.....but all the simple ones were taken.... :~)

Comment: Oh got it now! Anyway my comment is not meant to prohibit the use of such tools like Stirling.