# Proving a sequence $\frac{a^n}{n!}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Given any real $a$, I'm trying to prove by the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition that $\frac{a^n}{n!}$ converges. I know how to do this using the ratio test for sequences, but have no luck in using the formal definition, mainly because I cannot bound $n!$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $a$ is fixed, $n$ is not. Choose $N$ so $n \geq N$ implies $a/n$ is small enough, and use $n(n+1) \cdots (n +k - 1) > n^k$

Comment: Note that $n!\ge (n/2)^{n/2}$.

Comment: You should be able to get some ideas from the many proofs here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r

Answer (score 1):

One way is to notice that
if $n > 2a$ then
$\dfrac{a}{n} < \dfrac12$.

Then,
if $n > 2a$
and $m = \lfloor 2a\rfloor$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a^n}{n!}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n a}{\prod_{k=1}^n k}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^m a\prod_{k=m+1}^n a}{\prod_{k=1}^m k\prod_{k=m+1}^n k}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^m a}{\prod_{k=1}^m k}\dfrac{\prod_{k=m+1}^n a}{\prod_{k=m+1}^n k}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^m \dfrac{a}{k}\prod_{k=m+1}^n \dfrac{a}{k}\\
&<\dfrac{a^m}{m!}\prod_{k=m+1}^n \dfrac12\\
&=\dfrac{a^m}{m!}\dfrac1{2^{n-m}}\\
&=\dfrac{2^ma^m}{m!}\dfrac1{2^{n}}\\
\end{array}
$

For fixed $a$
(and thus $m$),
if we choose $n$ large enough so that
$\dfrac{2^ma^m}{m!}\dfrac1{2^{n}}
\lt \epsilon$,
then
$\dfrac{a^n}{n!}
\lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reprove the ratio test for this particular problem:

Let $b_n = \frac{a^n}{n!}$. Let $r_n = |\frac{b_{n + 1}}{b_n}| = \frac{|a|}{n}$. Since $r_n = \frac{|a|}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we can pick $N$ large enough so that
$$n \geq N \implies r_n < \frac{1}{2}.$$
We have
$$|b_{N + m}| = |b_{N}|r_{N}r_{N + 1}\dots r_{N + m} \leq |b_{N}|\frac{1}{2^{m + 1}} \to 0 \text{ as } m \to 0.$$
Thus $\lim_{m \to \infty}b_m = 0$.

Comment: Yep. Like mine but simpler.