# prove the sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{r^n}{n!} $ converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I tried using the definition $$if \quad \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathcal X_n = \mathcal L \quad then \quad |\mathcal X_n - \mathcal L| < \varepsilon \qquad for\; every \; \varepsilon >0$$

How do I break down $\ n! $ to use this

Comment: You can use d'Alembert test...

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550/42969, or one of these: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77550.