# The limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ where $x\in\mathbb R$

This is a common limit and has been asked and answered many times here on this site. However, I present another approach with Stolz-Cesaro($x\notin[-1,1]$. When $x\in[-1,1]$, the limit is trivially zero):

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}-x^n}{(n+1)!-n!}$$

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{(x-1)}{n}=L\frac{(x-1)}{n}$$

The above equation holds for all $x$ in domain only when $L=0$. Hence the limit is just $0$.

I have never seen Stolz-Cesaro being used this way to solve a limit, hence the lack of surety.  It would be great to get this verified!

Comment: That assumes $L$ exists.

Comment: For the calculation of that limit see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, Jose pointed it out in their answer. Is there a fairly simple way to show that the limit exists without actually computing it?

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh yes! I did go through that post before! I was very curious about this specific way of computing it

Comment: $(n+1)! - n! \ne n!$

Comment: @DatBoi When you take the limit, you cannot keep $n$ in $(x-1)/n$ and only let it $\to \infty$ in the first factor.

Comment: That's a huge blunder. The entire approach just crumbles then. Can a mod just delete this?

Comment: Maybe this slight modification may work: for sufficiently large $n$, $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is a decreasing sequence of $n$. And it is lower bounded by $0$. This guarantees the existence of $L$.

Answer (score 3):

You have not proved that the limit exists, what Stolz-Cesaro criterion says is the following:

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences, with $\{b_n\}$ monotone increasing and divergent. Then, if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lambda,\ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lambda$$
In order to use it you would have to calculate the limit after the second $=$ and then the criterion would guarantee that the limit you are actually trying to calculate is equal.

The most immediate way to see why it is zero is to notice that you are trying to calculate the limit of the general term of a convergent series (in this case the expansion of $e^x$), so it has to be zero.

Comment: It would really help if you could elaborate!

Comment: I see! Is there a simple way to show that the limit does exist, without actually computing it?

Comment: @DatBoi Maybe, but the most inmediate way to see why it is zero is to notice that you are trying to calculate the limit of the general term of a convergent series (in this case the expansion of $e^x$), so it has to be zero.

Comment: @JoséAntonio, but how do you show that the series converges? The argument for that has to include a direct proof that the limit of the terms is zero.

Comment: @Deane How is that? That the general term converges to zero is not a sufficient condition for convergence. Couldn't you just use the root test for series in order to find the radius of convergence? The calculation of op's limit is not neccesary to get the radius.

Comment: @JoséAntonio, all the OP wants is that the general term converges to zero. If you look at the proof of convergence of the series using the ratio test, you will see that the ratio test itself proves directly that the terms converge to zero. There's no need to go through the entire proof that the series converges. The proof that $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges to zero is much easier than the proof that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges.

Comment: @Deane I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (much less elegant) approach than the one taken in the answer of José Antonio.

**Given:** 
$~x~$ is some fixed (i.e. constant) real number.

It is sufficient to prove that

$~\forall ~\epsilon > 0, ~\exists ~M \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that
for all $~\displaystyle n \geq 2M, ~\left| ~\frac{x^n}{n!} ~\right| < \epsilon.$

---

For any **fixed** $~M \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ 
let $~f(k)~$ denote $(1 + 2M - k) \times k ~: 1 \leq k \leq M.$

Then, $~f'(k) = (1 + 2M) - 2k > 0 ~: ~1 \leq k \leq M.~$ 
Therefore, $~f(k)~$ is strictly increasing on the interval $~1 \leq k \leq M.$ 
Therefore, $(1 + 2M - k)k = f(k) \geq f(1) = 2M.$

Then

$$\left| ~\frac{x^{2M}}{(2M)!} ~\right| = \prod_{k=1}^M \frac{x^2}{f(k)} \leq  \left[ ~\frac{x^2}{2M} ~\right]^M = \left[ ~\frac{x^2}{M} ~\right]^M \times \frac{1}{2^M}. \tag1 $$

Given a fixed $~x \in \Bbb{R},~$ and given a fixed $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~M \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that:

- $~x^2 < M.$
- $~\dfrac{1}{2^M} < \epsilon.$

For example, using $~\lceil r\rceil~$ to denote the *ceiling* of $~r,~$ you can set

$$M = 1 + \max\left\{ ~\left\lceil ~x^2 ~\right\rceil, ~~\left\lceil ~\frac{\ln(1/\epsilon)}{\ln(2)} ~\right\rceil ~\right\}. \tag2 $$

With $~M~$ chosen by the constraint in (2) above, the RHS of (1) above is strictly $~\displaystyle < 1 \times \frac{1}{2^M} < \epsilon.$

Further, since $~M \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ and $~x^2 < M,~$ you have that $~|x| < M < 2M.$

The problem can now be completed by induction.

Let $~N~$ be any positive integer such that :

- $~|x| < N.$
- $\displaystyle \left| ~\frac{x^{N}}{N!} ~\right| < \epsilon.$

Then:

- $\displaystyle |x| < (N+1).$
- $\displaystyle \left| ~\frac{x^{N+1}}{(N+1)!} ~\right| = \left| ~\frac{x}{N+1} ~\right| \times \left| ~\frac{x^{N}}{N!} ~\right| < \epsilon.$

So, if the **two** inequalities above hold for $~N,~$ they also hold for $(N+1).$

Therefore, with $~M~$ set by the constraints in (2) above, for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that $~n \geq 2M,~$ the two inequalities will hold for $~n.$